# Получить две строчки в SQL запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно составить запрос.
Есть таблица с текстом. id, text
Я делаю запрос такого вида.

```
Select *
From text t
WHERE t.text LIKE %какой то текст%
```

Он мне возвращает весь текст. А как его обрезать? допустим что бы перед было одно предложение и после одно? Обрабатываю все в PHP.

Например строка такая.

это строка, это строка,это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, это строка, **какой то текст** это строка, это строка,  это строка, это строка,  это строка, это строка,  это строка, это строка,  это строка, это строка,

Обрезать хотя бы так

это строка, это строка, **какой то текст** это строка, это строка,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в примере вовсе не три предложения оставлено. может, тогда лучше сформулировать, что оставить сколько-то символов? strpos даст вам позицию искомого текста, отнимите нужное количество символов  - начало строки,  прибавьте нужное кол-во символов + длина искомого текста - конец строки. вырежьте  с помощью substr. Не забудьте проверить, что вы не вышли за границы строки

Comment: Спасибо получилось, только вот как проверить вышел ли я за границы строки?

Comment: то, что начало, должно быть больше нуля, то , что конец, меньше длинны

Comment: можете еще потерять немного времени и в циклах поискать первый пробел, чтоб не рвать слово

Comment: хм спасибо) щас попробую решить!

Comment: ну, будут проблемы с кодом, показывайте, посмотрим

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде бы получилось)

Comment: Отлично. рад был помочь